# HTML email signature creates attachments when forwarded from iPhone

Tags: html, css, iphone, outlook

I've created an HTML email signature for my company to implement. It seems to be working fairly well but I've come across 2 minor issues after a lot of testing. Our company is using Outlook 2013 on Windows for the vast majority.

1. When receiving an email on an iPhone, images still show up as attachments and then become attachments if forwarded.
2. I've seen a handful of people in our company whose images display larger in their signatures. I have not been able to replicate this issue myself but have seen the email signatures of others where the logos are enlarged.

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600px">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <p style="font-family:Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color:#004F59;"><span style="font-size:11pt;"><strong>First Last</strong> | Title</span>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size:10pt;"><strong>Conor Commercial Real Estate</strong></span></span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size:10pt; color:#666666;"><strong>Direct:</strong> 555.555.5555 | <span style="font-size:10pt; color:#666666;"><strong>Main:</strong> 847.692.8700 | <span style="font-size:10pt; color:#666666;"><strong>Fax:</strong> 555.555.5555 | <span style="font-size:10pt; color:#666666;"><strong>Mobile:</strong> 555.555.5555<br>
          9550 W. Higgins Road, Suite 200 | Rosemont, IL 60018<br>
          <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#666666;" href="mailto:name@conorcommercial.com">name@conorcommercial.com</a> | <a style="text-decoration:none; color:#666666;" href="http://www.conorcommercial.com" target="_blank">www.conorcommercial.com</a></span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="http://www.conorcommercial.com" target="_blank">
          <img border="0" width="121" height="48" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1560/23989160159_8db011822f_o.jpg" alt="Conor Commercial Real Estate" nosend="1">
        </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/conor-commercial-real-estate" target="_blank">
          <img border="0" width="28" height="50" src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5715/23521069649_011a8be7ee_t.jpg" alt="LinkedIn" nosend="1">
        </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/conorcommercial" target="_blank">
          <img border="0" width="28" height="50" src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5694/23593264840_b2f9f61da6_t.jpg" alt="Twitter" nosend="1">
        </a>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

We distributed these by sending the HTML file to everyone. They would then open the file in their browser, and copy/paste into Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

> The only reliable way to prevent this from happening, no matter which
>   mail client the recipient is using, is to place the picture of your
>   signature on a web server and then link to the picture in your
>   signature instead of sending the picture itself with each message.

Upload your file to server and then insert it from link (url) not as file.

Follow are the steps for different versions of Outlook:

**Outlook 2003 and previous**

- Right click in the Signature Editor and choose Insert Image…
- Then simply type the URL of the image in the “Picture Source” field.

**Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010**

- Use the Picture icon in the Signature Editor and type the URL of the
  image in the “File name” field.
- Click on the little down arrow on the Insert button and choose; Link
  to File

Comment: The images are being hosted on Flickr.

Comment: @JamesGGray I saw your code, and this is how it should be. Now, the rest depends on the email client receiving the email, and how to deal with. For example, the email client doesn't support HTML tags and convert your email to plain text, then definitely the signature logo turns into attachment.